# animateMotion fill="freeze" not work in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, animation, firefox, svg

I have a code like this, and it works in firefox(60.0.1) as expected: position of this 
`<path>` element stays at the end of the `<animateMotion>`, but in chrome(65.0.3325.146), this element returns to the starting position at the end of the animation.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="padding: 100px;" >
    <g>
        <animateMotion path="M70 -48 C70 -48 136 136 230 166 M230 166 C324 196 472 370 460 470" keyPoints="0;0;0.407;1" keyTimes="0;0;0.383;1" keySplines="0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5;0.167 0.167 0.833 0.833;0.167 0.167 0.833 0.833" dur="2" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" />
        <path fill="rgba(49, 187, 174, 1)" fill-opacity="1" d=" M37,17 C37,17 12.5,40.5 39,63 C65.5,38 37,17 37,17z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

there has a codepen demo: https://codepen.io/miaolegemie/pen/BxMjKM

Comment: report Chrome bugs to [chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: I have reported this, and it was accepted as a bug:https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=845375